# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am working on a text classification task using cnn, but I am getting an error.

My code:

```
input_layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.InputLayer()

#hidden layers
layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_len, trainable=False)(input_layer)

conv1d_1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D(8, 15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)
conv1d_2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)
conv1d_3 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)

layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.Concatenate()([conv1d_1, conv1d_2, conv1d_3])

layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.MalayerPooling1D(pool_size=10, strides=1, padding='same')(layer)

conv1d_4 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D(16, 15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)
conv1d_5 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)
conv1d_6 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D(96, 15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)

layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.Concatenate()([conv1d_4, conv1d_5, conv1d_6])

layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.MalayerPooling1D(pool_size=10, strides=1, padding='same')(layer)

layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D(50, 15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)

layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten()(layer)

layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(.3)(layer)

layer = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)

#output layer
output = Dense(20, activation='softmalayer', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)

#Creating a model
models = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
```

error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-230-c6e21e741579> in <module>
      7 
      8 #hidden layers
----> 9 layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_len, trainable=False)(input_layer)
     10 
     11 conv1d_1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D(8, 15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(layer)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    967               self._compute_dtype):
--> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\embeddings.py in call(self, inputs)
    179 
    180   def call(self, inputs):
--> 181     dtype = K.dtype(inputs)
    182     if dtype != 'int32' and dtype != 'int64':
    183       inputs = math_ops.cast(inputs, 'int32')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in dtype(x)
   1266 
   1267   """
-> 1268   return x.dtype.base_dtype.name
   1269 
   1270 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be careful not to bury the error message inside your code (edited).

Comment: `InputLayer` is an instance of `keras.Layer`, whereas `keras.layers.Input` is an instance of `Tensor`. The argument to `layer.__call__()` should be `Tensor` and not `keras.Layer`. Can you replace `input_layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.InputLayer()` to `input_layer = tf.keras.Input()`?